# JvectorMap Region Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, jvectormap

I am trying to reuse the region selection feature of JVectorMap. I am using a custom map (js) file. I have tested it in and it works fine for region selection.
Now I need to pass the regions which are selected by the user to the back end vb code. In this case maps.getSelectedRegions() gives an array of the user selected regions. I am not clear on how to pass a javascript array to back end vb code. The window.localstorage as how it is given in the example don't seem to work out here. Can somebody help me out on how this an be done?
This is the link of JVectorMap Region Selection - http://jvectormap.com/examples/regions-selection/

Following is the code I have used so far.

> ```
> <script>
> $(function(){   var maps;   maps = new jvm.WorldMap({
> container: $('#map'),
> map: 'xyz_map',
> regionsSelectable: true,
>
> regionStyle: {
>   initial: {
>     fill: '#B8E186'
>   },
>   selected: {
>     fill: '#F4A582'
>   }
> },
> series: {
>
> },
> onRegionSelected: function(){
>   if (window.localStorage) {
>     window.localStorage.setItem(
>       'jvectormap-selected-regions',
>       JSON.stringify(maps.getSelectedRegions())
>
>     );
>   }
> }
>    });   maps.setSelectedRegions( JSON.parse( window.localStorage.getItem('jvectormap-selected-regions') || '[]' )
>   );   });
>
>    </script>
> ```

Thanks in advance

Sina

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get a solution for this myself. You can add a hidden control in your asp code and assign the variable to this control.

> $(function(){   var maps,temp;   var hiddenControl = '<%=
>   inpHide.ClientID %>';   maps = new jvm.WorldMap({
>       container: $('#map'),
>       map: 'xyz_map',
>       regionsSelectable: true,
>
> ```
> regionStyle: {
>   initial: {
>     fill: '#B8E186'
>   },
>   selected: {
>     fill: '#F4A582'
>   }
> },
> series: {
>
> },
> onRegionSelected: function(){
> document.getElementById(hiddenControl).value=maps.getSelectedRegions();
> }   });
>
>            });
> ```